# Lenovo t430 Compatibility

Tags: lenovo-laptop, charger

Is a Lenovo t420 charger compatible with a t430 laptop? My t430 charger broke and I had to order a new one, but I accidently ordered a charger for the t420 laptop. Will it be compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Both machines use the same adapter.

https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/migr-62473

There is a 65-watt and 90-watt model. Both will work.

T430 Specs:

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd024705

T420 Specs:

https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/pd015734

AC Adapter specification is the same.